# AsyncData not being called in nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, asyncdata

I want to set category data at `asyncData()` hook. But `MainHeader` Page Component never calls `asyncData` even if it is placed in a page. Can you explain why `MainHeader` Page Component does not call `asyncData`?

`MainHeader` is placed inside "com" folder which is placed on pages (`/pages/com/MainHeader`)

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <header-nav :cateList="cateList"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HeaderNav from '~/components/com/nav/HeaderNav.vue';
import CateApi from "~/util/api/category/cate-api";

export default {
  components: {HeaderNav},

  async asyncData(){
    const cateList = await CateApi.getDispCateList();
    return{
      cateList,
    }
  },

  data() {
    return {
      cateList: [],
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

default
(`/layouts/default`)

```html
<template>
<div>
  <main-header/>
  <Nuxt/>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import MainHeader from "~/pages/com/MainHeader.vue"
export default {
  components :{
    MainHeader,
  },
  name: "defaultLayout"
}
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have access to the page? Can you add a simple piece of text to the `template`? Also, what if you try a `console.log` in a `mounted()`? No errors in the console? Nothing weird in the Vue devtools?

Comment: Also, you don't need `data`, `asyncData` will create that one via the `return`.

Comment: @kissu Thanks to reply! I've tried to console.log in asyncData, created, fetch, mounted. There are no errors in the console. Nothing weired in the devtools. At first request, server only calls created, fetch but not calls asyncData. I remove data but still asyncData not being called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably reaching your page directly, something like `/com/test-page` I guess, there you will get first initial result on the server (you can check, you'll be getting a `console.log` in there), which is legit because this is how Nuxt works (server-side first then client-side).

Please follow the convention of naming your pages like `my-cool-page` and not `myCoolPage` and also keep in mind that `asyncData` works only [inside of pages](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/data-fetching#async-data).

Your project is working perfectly fine, as an example, create the following file `/pages/com/main-header.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <p> main header page</p>
    <header-nav :cate-list="cateList" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HeaderNav from '~/components/com/nav/HeaderNav.vue';

export default {
  components: { HeaderNav },

  async asyncData() {
    console.log("check your server if accessing this page directly, otherwise you'll see this one in your browser if client-side navigation")
    const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
    const cateList = await response.json()

    return { cateList }
  },
}
</script>
```